# Issue using protobuf on android studio

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm new in using google RPC libraries for android stuff. I am trying to integrate the following link, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/android-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/Speech on my final year project which is an android chatbot. But I seems to be having hiccups. As after building using the following build.gradle, [myGradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoaRy.png). It seems that the build file "StreamingRecognizeResponse.java" does not have "IS_INITIALIZED, MAKE_IMMUTABLE & VISIT".

So I dig further and notice that they are using different GeneratedMessageLite.java file which is different from github.

In my case, the file is using fromprotobuf-javalite-3.11.0 while the example is using from protobuf-lite-3.0.1

I have found out that the example plugin is highlighted while mine isnt, and they are using different libraries also [exampleGradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYPRv.png).

If I right click on my "plugins" > go to > Declaration or usages. It shown me ProtobufConfigurator.groovy.
While the example one is using PluginAware.java.

I am stuck on this portion. Hope anyone would able to give me solution to this issue. Thanks!
Do let me know if there is any information I am lacking off!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protoc plugin version (i.e., protoc-gen-javalite) should always match the javalite runtime version, as there is [no API/ABI stability guarantee](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/java/lite.md) for protobuf lite.

Lite was recently re-integrated into `protoc`, so is no longer a separate plugin. To use the newer lite runtime swap to the newer protoc and specify the "lite" option to the `java` builtin.

```
protobuf {
  protoc {
    // must match protobuf-javalite version
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0'
  }
  plugins {
    grpc {
      artifact = "io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:${grpcVersion}"
    }
  }
  generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
      task.builtins {
        java { option 'lite' }
      }
      task.plugins {
        grpc { option 'lite' }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! just tried on your solution and it works! Thanks alot man!

Comment: If it worked and you are happy with it, then you should accept the answer.